# How I can force an implemented Class to use an Entity which has a specific Parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, implementation

I have an Interface as below:

```
  public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
```

T is type of my entities.
In this interface I have some methods which will use Entity's Id property. So, How can I guarantee that, **the Entity has Id property** when some body wants to implement this interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces to the rescue!

Define an interface as follows:

```
// Why IEquatable<T>? Because you don't want identifiers that may not
// be able to prove that they're equal or not. Most commonly used 
// types used as identifiers already implement IEquatable<T>. For example: 
// int, Guid...
public interface ICanBeIdentifiable<TId> where TId : IEquatable<TId>
{
    TId Id { get; }
}
```

...and change your repository interface signature as follows too:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, ICanBeIdentifiable<Guid>
...
```

...or if you want to absolutely open the door to any identifier type:

```
   public interface IRepository<TId, T> 
            where TId : IEquatable<TId>
            where T : class, ICanBeIdentifiable<TId>
```

The main drawback is your domain objects must implement the whole new interface, but it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional interface which will push every Entity to have Id property

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{

}
```